# Can I use a WIFI repeater as a local WIFI network AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, http, wireless-access-point, repeater

I'm trying to setup a local WIFI network, which has an additional internet connection via the repeated network.

Some background: I have an EPOS WIFI printer which is controlled over HTTP. Normally, I would hook up the printer to the WIFI network of a customer and a tablet to send print jobs over HTTP. Some customers however, isolate WIFI clients or block the HTTP port making it impossible to control the printer. (Example: The WIFI printer is at 10.0.0.22, the tablet at 10.0.0.28, but the tablet is not able to ping/ connect the the printer's HTTP page)

So in essence, would it be possible to setup the EPOS WIFI printer and tablet on a separate network (repeater?) so they remain connectable to each other over the repeater network, while using the repeated WIFI network to access the internet?

EDIT: Would a WIFI range extender be able to internally route traffic?

Comment: Could you provide more description on how the customers "isolate WiFi clients or block the HTTP port"?

Comment: No problem, I've updated the post

Comment: Use USB printing for that situation? Or install a USB wifi module and use that to connect to the printer directly.

Comment: Well the EPOS printer is a standalone WIFI printer already. The problem here is really the network of the client, isolating the WIFI clients. (Which they do deliberate). USB isnt an option for our product (the tablet which could potentially use USB is way out of reach)

Comment: Use @UserName to let UserName receive your comment. If so then bring a device that can act as an AP - like a real AP - and connect both device to it when prining. You need to add more detail about what you want to do.

Comment: You really need to have a talk with the customer's IT or Network support vendor and get these devices on their secure network or a vendor network without client isolation. Take it from an MSP, we would rather work with you to do it right then have you half-ass something that could seriously compromise network security and potentially get disconnected when we come onsite for an issue.

Comment: @acejavelin that would be the ideal outcome, though in our case we have many customers and short deadlines (last sunday we had to setup in a day and the IT department was one guy which was on holiday ;) )

Comment: For completeness, we ended up with a wifi tethering android app on the tablet itself, which creates a wifi network on the tablet to which the printer connects, while still being able to access the companies network. (The printer itself does not need access to the internet/ company network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeaters and range extenders don't have the logic required to perform the complete set of things an access point must do, so sorry, no.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does the same apply to WIFI range extenders? Or are there models which allow internal routing.